# symfony collection populate with multiple entries

Tags: symfony, collections, prototype, populate

I look for a way to populate my collection of forms. I am building my own collection through prototyping.

In my controller:

```
//samplecode... a person can have many cats
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$person= $em->getRepository('UserBundle:Person')->find(0);

$form = $this->createForm(new PersonType(), $person);
```

I have a collection of forms that i want populated with all the data (cats) that is already in my main entity (person). My last approach is commented out.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('cats', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new CatType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'mapped'=> false,
            'data_class' => 'Yoda\UserBundle\Entity\Cat',
//            'data' => $options["data"]->getCats(),
        ))
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

And the cat FormType:

```
->add('name', 'text', array(
    'read_only' => true,
    'disabled' => true,
))
->add('price', 'money', array(
    'label' => 'Price',
))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your form template:

```
{% for cat in form.cats %}
{{ cat.name }} {{ cat.price }}
{% endfor %}
```